# Azure Data Factory HDFS dataset preview error

Tags: hdfs, azure-data-factory, webhdfs

I'm trying to connect to the HDFS from the ADF. I created a folder and sample file (orc format) and put it in the newly created folder.

Then in ADF I created successfully linked service for HDFS using my Windows credentials (the same user which was used for creating sample file):
[image]

But when trying to browse the data through dataset:

[image]

I'm getting an error: **The response content from the data store is not expected, and cannot be parsed.**:
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrongly or it is kind of permissions issue?

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a generic issue, you need to point to a file with appropriate extension rather than a folder itself. Also make sure you are using a supported data store activity.

[image]
[image]

> [image]
>
> [image]

You can follow this official MS doc to use [HDFS server with Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-hdfs?tabs=data-factory)

Comment: In my example I'm pointing to exact file 000001_0, I tried to do the same with other formats like CSV and JSON, but still no luck. The case is that I even didn't move to any activity step, because I'm not able to see underlying data in the dataset itself, like I can do in other Linked services datasets (e.g., I can browsing folders in the ADLS even without specifying certain file).

Comment: Assuming you are using binary copy you are able to load data. Whats the source setting you have.